# Get enum based on addition value?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum defined as such:

```
private static enum COLOR {
    BLACK(Color.BLACK,"Black"),
    GREEN(Color.GREEN,"Green");

    private Color color;
    private String name;

    COLOR(String n, Color c) {
        this.name = n;
        this.color = c;
    }
```

Im trying to find a way to get the enum constant based on the *string* (which is the second additional parameter. So, for a completely hypothetical example, Id do something like

```
COLOR.getEnumFromString("Green")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public static COLOR getEnumFromString(final String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        for (COLOR v : values()) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(v.getValue())) {
                return v;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a `Map<String, COLOR>` and check the map in your `getEnumFromString`. I recommend something like the following:

```
 public enum COLOR{
       ....

       private static class MapWrapper{
           private static final Map<String, COLOR> myMap = new HashMap<String, COLOR>();
       }

      private COLOR(String value){
          MapWrapper.myMap.put(value, this);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a method on the enum declaration similar to the following :

```
private static enum COLOR {

    BLACK(Color.BLACK, "Black"),
    GREEN(Color.GREEN, "Green");

    private Color color;
    private String name;

    COLOR(Color c, String n) {
        this.name = n;
        this.color = c;
    }

    public static COLOR convertToEnum(String value) {
         for (COLOR v : values()) {
             if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(v.name)) {
                 return v;
             }
         }
         return null;
    }
}
```